# Different behaviour of column name between table and view

Tags: ruby, view, sequel

I have a table and a view based on the table:

```
require 'sequel'

db = Sequel.sqlite
db.create_table(:t1){
  String :f1
  String :f2
}
db.create_view(:v1, db[:t1].select(:f1))
```

If I create a dataset based on the table, the field name in the dataset an table are the same (`:f1`):

```
sel = db[:t1].select(:f1)
p sel.sql       #"SELECT `f1` FROM `t1`"
p sel.columns#[:f1]
```

But if I do the same with the view, the column name is changed from `:f1` to `:"'f1'"` (see the code example for correct value, I have to modify a bit for markdown)

```
sel = db[:v1].select(:f1)
p sel.sql         #"SELECT `f1` FROM `v1`"
p sel.columns  #[:"`f1`"]
```

How can I avoid this behaviour?

My environment:

- Win 7
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Sequel gem version "4.6.0".
- sqlite3-1.3.7-x86-mingw32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code in the rails console in a new rails app (3.2.15) with sequel added (4.6.0) and I did not see that behavior. Not sure what, but something is borked on your installation:

```
db = Sequel.sqlite
# => #<Sequel::SQLite::Database: {:adapter=>:sqlite}> 
db.create_table(:t1){
  String :f1
  String :f2
}
# => nil 
db.create_view(:v1, db[:t1].select(:f1))
# => nil 
sel = db[:t1].select(:f1)
# => #<Sequel::SQLite::Dataset: "SELECT `f1` FROM `t1`"> 
p sel.sql
# "SELECT `f1` FROM `t1`"
# => "SELECT `f1` FROM `t1`" 
p sel.columns#[:f1]
# [:f1]
# => [:f1] 
sel = db[:v1].select(:f1)
# => #<Sequel::SQLite::Dataset: "SELECT `f1` FROM `v1`"> 
p sel.sql
# "SELECT `f1` FROM `v1`"
# => "SELECT `f1` FROM `v1`" 
p sel.columns  #[:"`f1`"]
# [:f1]
# => [:f1]
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me ;) I used `sqlite3-1.3.7-x86-mingw32` and updated to `sqlite3-1.3.8-x86-mingw32` - Now my problem disappeared.

Comment: The reason it works with sqlite3-1.3.8-x86-mingw32 and not the previous version is that they upgraded the embedded SQLite from 3.7.13 to 3.7.17 (I think).  This was a bug in older versions of SQLite.